# What is the Kolmogorov complexity of arithmetic?

Tags: lo.logic, turing-machines, kolmogorov-complexity

[Chaitin's incompleteness theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity#Chaitin.27s_incompleteness_theorem) says no sufficiently strong theory of arithmetic can prove $K(n) > L$ where $K(n)$ is the Kolmogorov complexity of the number $n$ and $L$ is a sufficiently large constant. The size of $L$ depends on the theory.

Some people have suggested since the minimum value of $L$ depends on the theory, $T$, the minimum value of $L(T)$ can be used as a [measure of the complexity](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2011/09/the_inconsistency_of_arithmeti.html#c039544) of theory $T$. Other people have argued this is a [very bad idea](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/30226659?uid=3739960&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21106705767443). [At least one person has speculated](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2011/10/06/chaitins-theorem-and-the-surprise-examination-paradox/#comment-8118) the complexity of Peano arithmetic is less than $10^9$.

Assume we define $K(x)$ using n-state, 2-symbol [busy beavers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver#.CE.A3.2C_complexity_and_unprovability)(BB). $K(x)=n$ where $n$ is the number of states of the smallest BB that writes exactly $x$ 1's and halts. We don't really need a strong theory to write a computer program so assume our theory, $T$, is [primitive recursive arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_arithmetic). One way to define $L(PRA)$ is to define it as the size of a computer program that can determine the truth of any statement of the form $K(n) > m$ for any positive integers $n,m$. Assume the programming language is [x86 assembly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings). The size of the program is the size in bits of a compiled executable running on a 64-bit processor.

What is a reasonable value for $L(PRA)$? Are there any papers with upper bounds on $L(T)$ for some $T$?